# Magento product zoom extension not working in my custom theme

Tags: php, magento, plugins, themes, zooming

I am using a `custom theme in magento.` Now I install `a pluging for product zoom functionality`. But the plugin is not working. Finally I found that the while installing the plugin, the files are saved in default theme directory, but I am using a custom theme(themeheros).

To make the plugin working I cut and paste the

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/[extension_name].xml
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/[extension_name]/*
```

files to

```
app/design/frontend/[your_interface]/[your_theme]/layout/[extension_name].xml
app/design/frontend/[your_interface]/[your_theme]/template/[extension_name]/*
```

But no luck. The plugin is still not working.

For product zoom I use number of plugins but no one was worked in custom theme.

But in my local machine these plugins are working because there I am using the default theme.

How can I make the plugin working in Custom theme in Magento. My **magento version is 1.9.0.1**.

Comment: Check firebug error log. Maybe you included jquery more than one time (if you use jQuery). Check your zoomer initialization. Maybe some of the blocks (classes or ids) doesn't exist

Comment: In xml file there call some js files. But in page source of product page there is no such files.

Answer (score 0):

- Which javascript library does this module use? jQuery? Prototype? If
  jQuery check existing noConflict() method.
- Try to put layout and
  template files in base/default directory.
- In most situations any javascript lib doesn't work because of custom theme. For example in default magento image wrapper block is `<div class="product-image">` and any module try to select this block $('.product-image'). But in your custom theme this block can have another class and module initialization will not work. So I recommend to switch to default theme.
- Open on your product view page view:source code and find how much time jQuery (if it module use jQuery) attached
- According your comment check if current handle use on this page. Anyway upload here your layout xml in your first post.