# Issues regarding custom theme, plugins not working in Magento

Tags: php, magento, plugins, zooming

I am using magento custom theme. When I open my product page, while loading the page the `default zoom function buttons` are visible for a moment. When page load completely the buttons are disappear. 
Let us look the images for more info:

**Before (while loading)**

[image]

**After page load**

[image]

Why this happened so? I am installed a new custom theme. This theme not provide any image zoom functionality. I think the zoom buttons are load from `frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\media.phtml.` Why my site load this page, since I use a custom theme the site should use the `theme's media.phtml file.` How can I solve this issue?

And when I try to install some `product zoom plugins`, these are not working in my theme. The plugin files are saved in my default theme directory. And I manually copy the plugin files from default to custom theme directory, but no luck. Please refer the [**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489367/magento-product-zoom-extension-not-working-in-my-custom-theme) for more details. Is there any way to rectify this?

Please help me ...I am using **magento 1.9.0.1**

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check which package you are using for you theme, you can check if media.phtml is being called from rwd folder.

```
i.e. /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view
```

Or you can enable path hints and locate the phtml files, and accordingly that you can put the design files of custom module there.

To turn on template path hints in Magento:

- log into the magento back-end admin.
- Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu.
- Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED.
- Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store
  view.

or check the below link.

https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-

Comment: thanks for your reply.My custom theme's media.phtml is loaded in product page.

Comment: Did you find from which location the media.phtml loads by enabling path hints? can you check which package you are using? You need to put the custom templates in that package.